# I always have the same student which appears after each recording

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

When I add a recording, I always have the same student which appears ???

[image]

Edit my problem is solved

[image]

I think the problem is perhaps in my function index() ?

```
public function index(Request $request)
  {   
     $user = $request->user();
     $payments = Payment::query()
     ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
     $query->where('email', $user->email);
     })
     ->when($request->has('search'), function (Builder $query) use ($request) {
    $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
         })->with('students:id,name') 
    ->paginate(5);

    return view('admin.payments.index', compact('payments'))
    ->with('display_search', $user->hasRole('admin'));
    }
```

For information my table students has 3 fields `(id, name, email)` and the table payments has 6 fields `(id, date_payment, number_seance, price, total, fk_student)`.

My relationships:

Model **Student**:

```
protected  $fillable = ['user_id', 'name', 'email', 'payment_id'];

public function payments(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Payment', 'fk_student');
    }

  public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'payment_id');
    }
```

Model **Payment**:

```
protected  $fillable = ['date_payment', 'fk_student', 'number_seance',  'price', 'total'];

    public function students(){

    return $this->belongsTo('App\Student', 'fk_student');
    }

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'id', 'payment_id');
    }
```

Model **User**

```
public function students()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Student', 'user_id', 'id');
    }

    public function payments()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Student', 'payment_id', 'id');
    }
```

Index blade

```
<th>Date payment</th>
<th>Number seance</th>
<th>Price</th>
<th>Total</th>
 <th>Name</th>

</tr>
</thead>
@foreach($payments as $payment)
<tr>
   <td> {{$payment->date_payment->format('d/m/Y') }}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->number_seance}}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->price}}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->total}}</td>
   <td> {{$payment->students->first()->name}}</td> 
   <td>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to show the relevant sections of the view, as well as the relationship definitions on your models.

Comment: Is that Remacle the name of a student or a payment?  IE when searching, what are you searching on?

Comment: @patricus: Sorry, I changed my first message.

Comment: @Watercayman: "Remacle" is the name of a student who has paid. The administrator encodes the names of the students.
After that I would like each student to log in and check his payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like both of those queries are trying to query against fields that don't exist on the model you are querying against.

If a user doesn't have admin rights, I think you are trying to just send payments that this particular user has made.  But, I don't see where you are linking the related tables to query against the user.  This part:

```
 $payments = Payment::query()
     ->when($user->hasRole('admin') !== true, function (Builder $query) use ($user) {
      $query->where('email', $user->email);
 })
```

appears to be looking for an `email` field on your **Payment** model.  But you said that there wasn't one.  You also said there was no email on your student, so I'm not sure how you can connect payment to an email address.  IF you had a relationship between user and payment, you could do something like this:

```
$payments = Payment::whereHas('user', function($query) use($user){
     $query->where('users.email', $user->email); 
     // etc.
```

And get the payments associated with that user.  But there is no FK to do this at present.

It also appears the second part of that query:

```
 $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
     })->with('students:id,name')
```

is trying to query against the name of a **Payment**, and I don't think this will work since there isn't a name field on the **Payment** model.  If you were trying to get payments for the student in the search, something more like this might work:

```
$payments = Payment::whereHas('student', function($query) use($request){
      $query->where('name', 'like', '%' . $request->input('search') . '%');
      // etc.
```

Note student model relation on payment should be singular (student, not students) to prevent confusion.

This code is not going to solve this - there are a number of items that need attention (I think).  But, the big issue that I can see is that you need to push the query against the relationship fields, and not the **Payment** model.  Hopefully you can see where I was trying to go with the related queries and figure out how to tweak your code.

Comment: Thanks for the time you spent on answering me, actually I have an email field in my table student, sorry for this forget!

I edited my first message, what do you think about my relationships?

Comment: Change students() to student() on **payment**.  It is one to one.  Thus in your blade, `$payment->students->first()->name` isn't correct - it should be `$payment->student->name`.  That will make a difference.  The answer above should get you to where you want to go... but you will need to work with it to make it exactly what you want.  It is close :)

Comment: Hmm, the student relationship type on payment doesn't make sense - now that you've posted them, those keys wouldn't be right I don't think. Looks more like a hasOne than belongs to. Suggest you go back to these and review all of your relationships and FKs carefully against the docs and what you have named your database fields.  BUT - the belongsTo can't be same for user and student - they are different relationships. Review this :)

Comment: Thank you my problem displaying users is resolved.(see first message)  I will open another post about my relationships because I can not solve the problem.

Comment: can you help me one last time on a small problem please? sorry to bother you always => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58210647/checking-payment?noredirect=1#comment102798771_58210647

Comment: It's no problem at all :)  I'm offline tonight, but I added what I think the problem is.