# Checking payment

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

For each payment, the student can follow a training.

For example, I encode a payment for the student `Menier`.

[image]

Then, I encode a training for the student `Menier`.

[image]

It's correct !

Now, when I encode another payment for the same student `Menier`

[image]

I can't add a training, it's blocking ???

[image]

How to put to zero the checking, after each payment of the student?

```
$conflitpayment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
        ->whereDate('date_payment', ">" , $date_seance)
        ->first();

        if(isset($conflitpayment)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('error', 'Payment! ');
        }

        $thisStudentsTrainings = Training::with(['payments' => function($query) use($fk_student){
        $query->where('fk_student', $fk_student);
        }])->get();

        $hasPaidForThisTraining = $thisStudentsTrainings ->contains('id', $request->get('fk_training'));



        if( count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= 1) { 
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'No payment ! ');
        }



        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
        }
```

Thank you for your help.

Controller **Training**

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
                'fk_former' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required',
                'fk_typeseance' => 'required'


        ]);


       $date_seance = $request->get('date_seance'); 
       $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
       $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
       $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
       $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');
       $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
       $fk_typeseance = $request->get('fk_typeseance');

       $paiements = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->first();

        if(!isset($paiements)){ 
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('error', 'No payment, no training!');
        }


        $conflitpayment = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))
        ->whereDate('date_payment', ">" , $date_seance)
        ->first();

        if(isset($conflitpayment)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('error', 'Payment! ');
        }


        $PaymentHasBeenMadeForThisTraining = Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student)  
        ->where('fk_training', $request->get('fk_training')) 
        ->first(); 

        $thisStudentsTrainings = Training::with(['payments' => function($query) use($fk_student){
        $query->where('fk_student', $fk_student);
        }])->get();

        $hasPaidForThisTraining = $thisStudentsTrainings->contains('id', $request->get('fk_training'));



        if( count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= 1) { 
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('error', 'No payment ! ');
        }



        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
        }



    }
```

Comment: You get any error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what this controller is, or what is feeding it.  But, it appears that the code is working correctly against what it is written to do.  It looks to be blocking a student from adding a payment to a training that he has already paid for.

This line:

```
$hasPaidForThisTraining = $thisStudentsTrainings ->contains('id', $request->get('fk_training'));
```

Looks at all trainings that a student has, and then checks to see if the training id passed from the form is the same one that he is trying to pay for.  If it is a match, then block him from making the payment.  That seems to work (though I'm not sure about the very first query for `$conflitpayment` being needed or if it is correct - but that's not the issue here).  What I don't understand is why there are checks for payments made in the same section as the creation of a new training.  Checks for multiple payment should probably be in the **payment creation** method, not the training - since you are trying to block multiple payments, not necessarily trainings.

What I suspect might be happening, is that this form for *adding a new training* is running through the *payment* form.. OR the payment and training forms are going through the same method in your controller.  IE you have a field of `fk_training` on the form, and it is coming in to this method with a value.  If you are creating a new training, you should not have a `fk_training` field in that method.  Separate the logic of the if-checks on payments from the logic on creating a new payment into different methods and this should solve your problem.

If this field is coming through the form, and it is an existing training, even on the payment method, this will block the **creation of a new training**.

**EDIT**

You note in the comments "1 payment for 2 trainings. After, the 2 trainings, I pay again."  This is very different from what the code does.  The code previously checked if a student paid for *this* particular training, and if so, stop the payment.  The logic behind your comment is now very different.  And makes the code more complicated.

There are some questions that you need to answer in order for this to work.  First, they pay for two different trainings?  If so, do we still want to prevent them from paying for the same training twice?  I assume yes, which means the `$hasPaidForThisTraining` check is correct.

But, if **not**, and they **can** pay for two trainings of the same ID, then we have to change the if-check to count how many times he has paid for the same query.  Right now, it will fail if they paid ONCE.

```
if( count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= 1) { }  // CHANGE TO >=2
```

Or you might be wanting to check if they have paid for two trainings and those have expired?  IE they now need to pay again?  This is not too hard if you have a payment attached directly to the student's training and you can only pay for one training:

```
  $PaymentHasBeenMadeForThisTraining = Payment::where('fk_student', $fk_student)  
    ->where('fk_training', $request->get('fk_training')) 
    ->first();
```

You can do that for each training that you need to check if they have paid.  However, where this gets complex - is if you are saying they can pay for any two trainings and then if they have taken those trainings, then they need to pay again.  You will need to tighten the logic down before you can code it.  What are the parameters that allow for a payment to be 'used'?  Is it based on date?  If so, what if the student didn't take the course?  How do you account for that in the code?  Or, what if they paid for one and want to buy two others?  Can they do this, and if so, what is the determination to know that the second payment is made against?

I can't represent this in code because I can't understand all the rules, which you need to know in order to constrain it in code.  I suggest you simplify this way down.  Let the method above in your question just do **one** or two things - maybe check to see if a payment has been made for the course in question.  Then another check to see if they have 'credit' left.

I don't think you will ever get to create a training in that method.  If there is a foreign key for `fk_training` (which MUST be in this function or the queries will fail), there is ALREADY a training that may or may not hit the if-checks.  So it will never create a new one as it is currently coded.  I suggest you re-think how this section works, and separate out the payment checks from *creation* of a new training.  IE did they pay for THIS training?  OK, if so, do they have credit left for the NEXT training?  If not, flag that they are out of credit **on the form**, before they are given a chance to create a training.  Get the payment first as a separate action - then once they have credit, then allow for creation of a new training.

This is hard to even explain - I think you will make your life a lot easier if you simplify this down.  Previously you were OK to check payment against training - one to one, and that worked fine based on those rules.  If you want to allow for 2 payments, you either need to come up with complex rules... OR just let the payment be a credit on the student account and they can take a course based on having credit in the system.  Much simpler if your real world usage can handle this solution.

Comment: Why there is a check in the "training" section. Because you have to pay (immediately the training) before following the training.

For my problem, the rule is simple: 1 payment for 2 trainings.
After, the 2 trainings, I pay again. the student is entitled to 2 new trainings, but I do not know how to create the algorithm. because it blocks as a duplicate. :-(

Comment: In fact, there is only one rule I would like to address ...
It's a payment every 2 trainings.
For example: we have a payment on October 04, 2019, so we will have a training on October 05, 2019 and October 06, 2019, if I add a training on October 7, 2019 I have a message that tells me that I reached the limte (the ceiling)

We need a new payment ... For example the 08 October 2019 I pay... and we can add 2 trainings on 09 October and 10 October.

A payment is equal to 2 mandatory trainings ...
I do not know how to create this kind of algorithm in fat ??

Comment: I see.  While it appears only one rule, this is actually several.  To do this, and include the date and mandatory payment trainings, I recommend you remove the `fk_training` from the payment model.  Separate training / payment.  Then, compare on a credit system - do you have enough payments to purchase a training?  Then, you can compare against the ceiling or dates based on the payment date or payment FOR date.  This is a complicated rule set - you will need to refactor based on above.  But, to leave the tie to the training will make this extremely hard to code.  Suggest separation.

Comment: Ok, thank you I'll still reflect  about it tonight :)

Comment: I deleted several fields, I created a new topic to be more precise. If you have a moment the time, I would like to have your opinion, because I am completely blocked => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58242345/verification-of-payments-and-ceiling-of-trainings-in-laravel

Comment: Sure - it's now a little easier.  I've written an answer that should solve it for you :)