# Adapt my method store () for update () in Laravel 5.6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Here is my method store(). there is a check on the ceiling not to be reached.

For information, the code is correct for the method store().

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required'


        ]);


       $date_seance = $request->get('date_seance'); 
       $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
       $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
       $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');

        $thisStudentsTrainings = Training::where('fk_student', $fk_student)->get();

        $thisStudentsPayments = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->get();


        if(count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= count($thisStudentsPayments) * 5) {
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index') 
                ->with('error', 'ceiling reached!'); 
        }


        else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
        }


    }
```

I want to create my method update () but I am stuck ...
I don't understand how I could adapt my code of my method store in my method update() ?

I want to do 2 things:

1) change a value of a field

2) checking the ceiling

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{  


   $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required',


        ]);


   if{
       $trainings = Training::find($id);
       $trainings->date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');
       $trainings->hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
       $trainings->hour_end = $request->get('hour_end ');
       $trainings->fk_student = $request->get('fk_student ');
       $trainings->save();
       return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
              ->with('success', 'Update!')->withInput();

   }

}
```

Edit 13/10/19 Code **Watercayman**

```
protected function doCeilingCheck($training)
    {
        $thisStudentsTrainings = Training::where('fk_student', $training->fk_student)->get();

        $thisStudentsPayments = Payment::where('fk_student', $training->fk_student)->get();


        if(count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= count($thisStudentsPayments) * 2) {
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index') 
            ->with('error', 'ceiling reached!'); 
        }else{

            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
        }
    }

    /**
     * Show the form for editing the specified resource.
     *
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $trainings = Training::find($id);
        $students = Student::all();
        $formers = Former::all();
        $motorbikes = Motorbike::all();
        $payments = Payment::all();

        return view('admin.trainings.edit', compact('trainings', 'students', 'formers', 'motorbikes', 'payments'));
    }

    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  int  $id
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
                'fk_former' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required'
        ]);


        $trainings = Training::find($id);
        if($this->doCeilingCheck($trainings)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('success', 'Update!')->withInput();
        }else{ 
            $trainings->date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');
            $trainings->hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
            $trainings->hour_end = $request->get('hour_end');
            $trainings->fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
            $trainings->fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
            $trainings->fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');
            $trainings->save();
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index') 
            ->with('error', 'ceiling reached!'); 
        }

    }
```

After, a modification in my form, I have 2 messages that appear.

[image]

There is a problem with my condition I think?

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking here. What do you mean by "adapt this code"? Wouldn't your ceiling check only apply to creating new resources, not updating existing ones?

Comment: @Aken Roberts: I have edited my first message...Is it clear ?

Comment: It looks like, when you update a Training record, you want to allow it to be assigned to a new student. And if so, check to make sure that student's ceiling hasn't been reached. If you don't want to allow a Training to be assigned to a new student, just remove that part and you don't need to check the ceiling. If you do, just add the same ceiling check to the update method.

Comment: @Aken Roberts: I want to check the ceiling and modify, for example, the values of my fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a number of ways to do this.  It depends on what you are trying to achieve.

**Method 1, Simple:**

If you want to simply update the training model with anything that is sent (and then check for ceiling), you can automate much of this with a route-model binding.

In your **web.php**:

```
Route::put('training/{training}', 'TrainingController@update');
```

Then in your **TrainingController**:

```
public function update(Request $request, Training $training){
    if($this->doCeilingCheck($training))
        $training->update($request->all());
    else{ // return ceiling met }
```

**Method 2, Not Binding**:

Your route would be the same as it is now, and your function would no longer have the injected model, but similar flow.

In your **TrainingController**:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id){
    $training = Training::find($id);
    if($this->doCeilingCheck($training)){
        $training->update($request->all());
    }else{ // return ceiling met }
```

**Method 3, filter fields:**

If you didn't want to pass *every* variable through to your updated training model after the update, you can filter out what you want and just save like you did earlier.  This is potentially what is causing you problems.  Are you updating Student A's training by a user who is not Student A?  Thus possibly changing the fk_student to the wrong student and also causing a ceiling reached because of the wrong student?:

**Inside your TrainingController** after passing if-check for ceiling:

```
   $trainings->date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');
   $trainings->hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
   $trainings->hour_end = $request->get('hour_end ');
   // Maybe you don't want to allow change to FK - just remove this next line
   // $trainings->fk_student = $request->get('fk_student '); 
   $trainings->save();
```

**Ceiling Check**:

I moved this to a separate function within the same controller just to make this a little easier to understand.  You don't have to do this - you can keep the code in `update()` if you like.  The key is that we need to check to see if the STUDENT FOR THIS TRAINING has paid for too many trainings.  So, we want to make sure to **use the student from the training** in question (`$training->fk_student`), **not** the student filling out the form (`$request->get('fk_student')`).

Optionally further down **in your TrainingController**:

```
protected function doCeilingCheck($training){
    $thisStudentsTrainings = Training::where('fk_student', $training->fk_student)->get();

    $thisStudentsPayments = Payment::where('fk_student', $training->fk_student)->get();


    if(count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= count($thisStudentsPayments) * 5) {
        return false
    }else{
        return true;
    }
}
```

**Edit**:

You have a rigid check to see if the student has touched his ceiling for # of trainings and payments.  This will work fine for your `store()` method, because the counts will be changing after the addition of a new training.  IE you haven't *made* the 2nd training yet in the `store()` method until after the if-check, so the ceiling isn't reached.  However, in the `update()` method, the training ceiling *may* have been reached already and thus you may hit a false ceiling **even though you are not adding a new training or changing the amount of payments or trainings in any way**.  Programatically - you can get around this by allowing +1 trainings against your normal ceiling:

```
// Instead of the 5 you have in your code:
if(count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= count($thisStudentsPayments) * 6)
```

However, this is hackish, and from a logic standpoint, I would ask yourself what is the point of this check during an **update**?  The student is not changing the number of trainings, they are not changing the number of payments.  So the check to see if they are over the ceiling probably should be ignored on an update.  They are simply changing like for like numbers - they are changing the details of the course, NOT the number of them.  I suggest removing that check entirely from the `update()` method to make this work as you had intended.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation... I have edited my first message with your code. In fact, when I modify a value in my form. I have two messages that appear those of my conditions ???

Comment: `doCeilingCheck()` needs to return `true` or `false` and then handle that in the main method.  If you are calling this method from an if check like I have set up above (`if($this->doCeilingCheck($training))`), and you are returning a `return redirect()` like you set up in your code, this will not work correctly and sometimes send 2 responses.  If easier, just move the `doCeilingCheck()` into your `update()` method.  There is another problem, however, which I will edit into the end of my answer.

Comment: @ Watercayman: Ah, thank you for your explanations. The second problem is according you ?

Comment: See the edit above.  I think this check for ceiling should be removed from the `update()` method.  This will solve your problem and avoid a non-useful bit of logic.

Comment: I think you're right, I'm going to delete this ceiling check by removing the `fk_student` in my form edit

Comment: Good idea.  Because it doesn't matter - you won't want to change that for the update.  But, also, the whole count of trainings vs. payments is also mute for this - I would get rid of it in the `update()` method -- just update, don't check for payments since that won't be changing.

Comment: @ Watercayman:  You are right... :-) I'm sorry if I took you a lot of time. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: No worries, glad that it helps you!

Comment: How handle you correctly the dates and hours? I always have several worries? :-( https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58382052/how-to-correctly-handle-dates-and-times

Comment: Sure - I'll take a look :)

Answer (score 1):

is the same just change the else for the update

```
public function update(Request $request,$id)
{
    $request->validate([
            'date_seance' => 'required',
            'hour_start' => 'required',
            'hour_end' => 'required',
            'fk_student' => 'required'


    ]);


   $date_seance = $request->get('date_seance'); 
   $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
   $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
   $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');

    $thisStudentsTrainings = Training::where('fk_student', $fk_student)->get();

    $thisStudentsPayments = Payment::where('fk_student', $request->get('fk_student'))->get();


    if(count($thisStudentsTrainings) >= count($thisStudentsPayments) * 5) {
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index') 
            ->with('error', 'ceiling reached!'); 
    }


    else{
   $trainings = Training::find($id);
   $trainings->date_seance = $request->get('date_seance');
   $trainings->hour_start = $request->get('hour_start');
   $trainings->hour_end = $request->get('hour_end ');
   $trainings->fk_student = $request->get('fk_student ');
   $trainings->save();
   return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
          ->with('success', 'Update!')->withInput();
    }


}
```

Comment: thank you but when I change the value of a field ... I have a message that tells me that the ceiling is reached