# How to correctly handle dates and times?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

In my model `Training` I have a recording.

[image]

date training : 15/09/2019 | hour_start : 18:00 | hour_end : 20:00 | motorbike : 000001

Then, if I have the motorbike `000001` in `Revision`, on 01/09/2019 to 15/09/2019 from 14:00 to 16:00.

[image]

Now, If I want to add a recording in my form `Training` for example :

[image]

date training : 15/09/2019 | hour_start : 08:00 | hour_end : 10:00 | motorbike : 000001

Normally, the motorbike is in revision, but here I can the add ??? How to create a blocking?

```
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
                'date_seance' => 'required',
                'hour_start' => 'required',
                'hour_end' => 'required',
                'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
                'fk_former' => 'required',
                'fk_student' => 'required',
                'fk_typeseance' => 'required'


        ]);


       $date_seance = Carbon::parse($request->get('date_seance'))->format('Y-m-d');
       $hour_start = $request->get('hour_start'); 
       $hour_end = $request->get('hour_end'); 
       $fk_motorbike = $request->get('fk_motorbike');
       $fk_student = $request->get('fk_student');
       $fk_former = $request->get('fk_former');
       $fk_typeseance = $request->get('fk_typeseance');


       $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike')) 
       ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , Carbon::parse($date_seance)) 
       ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
       ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
       ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
       ->first();

      $conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
       ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance)) 
       ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
       ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
       ->whereDate('date_revision_end', "<=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance))
       ->first();

      if(isset($conflictRevision)) {
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
             ->with('error', 'revision');
        }

       if(isset($conflictTraining)){
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
             ->with('error', 'training');
        }

      else{
            Training::create($request->all());
                return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                    ->with('success', 'Add');
        }



    }
```

I think my problem is here with the hours ?

```
$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
       ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance)) 
       ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
       ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
       ->whereDate('date_revision_end', "<=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance))
       ->first();
```

I think you in advance.

Comment: hour_start is a string? or a datetime? i think the best way you can do it is with thats attibutes make a datetime

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure what the error is.  Your code as written seems to be correctly letting the bike in revision enter a new training.  In this line:

```
$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
   ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance)) 
   ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
   ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
   ->whereDate('date_revision_end', "<=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance))
   ->first();
```

your code is asking to find any bike in revision within a specific date range **and within a certain hour range**.  According to your form screenshot above, you have a bike that is requesting training on 15/9.  Normally that would produce a conflict message, since the bike is in revision.  If your query for this conflict was this:

```
$conflictRevision = Revision::where('fk_motorbike', $fk_motorbike)
   ->whereDate('date_revision_start', "<=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance)) 
   ->whereDate('date_revision_end', ">=" ,  Carbon::parse($date_seance))
   ->first();
```

The if-check would produce a conflict since the bike is in revision on 15/9 and you want another training on 15/9.  However! You have also included the time in the query.  You and i know that the bike is in revision all day on 15/9.  But you have further constrained the query to say "tell me all bikes in revision on 15/9 AND only tell me if they are in revision between 08:00 and 10:00".  This produces NO bikes in revision because the *query* asked for bikes on that day **and within that time frame on that day**.

**Solution 1:**

You can keep the times in the query, which would translate to what we said above - it is OK to book the bike into training even though it is in revision on that day, **as long as it isn't during those hours**.

**Solution 2:**

Or, you can remove the time from the query like in my second code above. This would translate to "is the Bike in revision at any time at all during that day, and if so, block the training".  This second one seems more logical from a real world flow to me.

Comment: Thank you a lot for your explanation. I also read that we could add two more variables, start_time and stop_time. If a day,  you have 15 minutes and it is not complicated I would like to understand how it works I can not find documentation in French. Otherwise, it does not matter I will keep the solution 2. :-)

Comment: It isn't a thing you would find in documentation, unfortunately.  This is pure program logic.  Your code was correct - it was doing exactly what you asked it to do.  But, the logic of what you were asking was not correct for what you wanted.  You either need to allow training for times on those days when it is in revision, or not - it is up to you.  The hard part to understand is that you can't have both; only one or the other will work in terms of how you will constrain this.

Comment: I will follow your advice. :) Thank you.

Comment: several persons use a start_time and stop_time, do you know how to do it? I am stuck in the duplicate for the controller Training.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58456553/adapt-my-code-by-adding-start-time-and-stop-time-in-my-booking

Comment: Sure - I stick in an answer.  The trick is to keep it to integers.