# Adapt my code by adding start_time and stop_time in my booking

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have to add in my `TrainingController` two variables => `start_time` & `stop_time`.

In my old code I had this:

```
 $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->get('fk_motorbike')) 
 ->whereDate('date_seance', "=" , Carbon::parse($date_seance)) 
 ->where('hour_start', "<=" , $request->get('hour_start')) 
 ->where('hour_end', ">=" , $request->get('hour_end'))
 ->where('fk_former', $request->get('fk_former'))
 ->first();
```

My problem is that I would like to do a checking. How Can I avoid a duplicate for my request `$conflictTraining` with `start_time` & `stop_time`..

Here is my code for now:

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $request->validate([
            'date_seance' => 'required',
            'hour_start' => 'required',
            'hour_end' => 'required',
            'fk_motorbike' => 'required',
            'fk_former' => 'required',
            'fk_student' => 'required',
            'fk_typeseance' => 'required'


        ]);


        $start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_seance . ' ' . $hour_start);
        $stop_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_seance . ' ' . $hour_end);


        $conflictTraining = Training::where('fk_motorbike', $request->fk_motorbike)
            ->where('start_time', "<=", $start_time)
            ->where('stop_time', ">=", $stop_time)
            ->first();


        if (isset($conflictTraining)) {
            return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
                ->with('error', 'training duplicate');
        }


        $data = $request->all();
        $data['start_time'] = $start_time;
        $data['stop_time'] = $stop_time;
        Training::create($data);
        return redirect()->route('trainings.index')
            ->with('success', 'Add');


    }
```

I thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking how to add a new constraint for a couple of new database fields, `start_time` and `stop_time`, I think you are pretty close with your current query for `$conflictTraining`.

You didn't state what the specific problem was, but I'm guessing that these lines:

```
$start_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_seance . ' ' . $hour_start);
$stop_time = Carbon::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:s', $date_seance . ' ' . $hour_end);
```

are producing something that doesn't match the format in the database for `start_time` and `stop_time`.  If you break down what you have created in those variables, you are basically telling Carbon to make a variable that looks something like this:  "15-10-2019 10:00:00" (with the caveat that the 00 is seconds, not minutes since you used `s` instead of `i`).

So your first question should be, 'is my database storing the start time in the exact format that shows when I dump `$start_time`?'  If not, the query will never produce a hit.  You can certainly store your start times and stop times in the database as a a date and time... but keep in mind, **you will be constrained by the date as well as the time** if you do so. In other words, if you just want a start time to be 10:00 on any day, that won't work because the database is storing 10:00 *on a specific date*.

One way to resolve this is to keep this as simple as possible.  If those times are NOT linked to a specific date, and are always going to be on the hour - save them as a simple number.  E.g. `08` or `22`.  Then, you don't need to use Carbon, you are just comparing simple integers.  If you want to use an actual time (you might want 18:20 or something), this is not much more complex - you just need to change the way you store and create the time.

You can play with this, but the general idea would be to just store / create the time in a consistent format between database and what you create from the form.  So for `start_time`, you could perhaps save the hours and minutes in a different column.  Or calculate the number of minutes after midnight and store as an integer.  Or even store as text and use Carbon on both sides to make into a formatted object.

Personally I find it easiest to work with integers, so I would make a calc (maybe mins past midnight) and use that calc across the program to just stay with integers.  There are a lot of ways to solve this - hopefully this explains the issue to you.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. with my request $conflictTraining  I can only add one record per date, I find this too weird.

Comment: Yes, this is correct against your code.  Your code is asking if there are any trainings **on any date at all** that are between x hour and x hour.  If you want to record one more, you will need to add a line in there to check against the `date_seance` field too within that same query to narrow the query to *just one day at that time*.  But, good news is that you appear to have solved your `start_time` `stop_time` problem :)

Comment: Yes, thank you very much for your explanations. I learned a lot with you.